# MongoDB: group, and then counting different values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a list of books. I would like to get the number of genres that the authors wrote, also I would like to add to the results which are those genres. My database looks like this:

```
{"_id": ObjectID("1), "title": "Harry Potter", "year": NumberInt(2000), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Fantasy"}, 
"_id": ObjectID("2"), "title": "Harry Potter 99", "year": NumberInt(2020), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Drama"}, "_id": ObjectID("2"), "title": "Harry Potter", "year": NumberInt(2000), "author": "JK. Rowling", 
"genres": "Drama"}, {...}
```

So, my code so far looks like this:

```
phase1 = {$group : {"_id" : "$author"}, "countgenres" : {$sum : 1}}
phase2 = {$addFields : "genres"}}
phase3 = {$sort : {"numgenres" : -1}}

steps = [phase1, phase2, phase3]
db.database.aggregate(steps)
```

This is not working for me, so I would like if someone could help me to write a correct code to do this. The result should look like this:

```
{

"_id" : "JK. Rowling",

"countgenres" : 4,

"genres" : [

"War",
"Fantasy",
"Drama",
"Crime"

]
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "author": "JK. Rowling"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$author",
      "genres": {
        "$addToSet": "$genres"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      genres: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$genres",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "countgenres": {
        "$size": "$genres"
      },
      "genres": 1
    }
  }
])
```

First stage is `$match` by the author.

Then group and I've used `$addToSet` to avoid repeated values.
After that, with `$addFields` values are merged.

After the group, the field `genres` is output like this:

```json
"genres": [
      [
        "War",
        "Fantasy",
        "Drama",
        "Crime"
      ],
      [
        "War",
        "Fantasy",
        "Drama"
      ]
    ]
```

And to merge is neccessary to do `$setUnion`.

And, the last step is count the array size and output the values you want.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHvnGiPVp8q)

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've just realized that I posted a wrong database example, in my database all there is only one genre per document (I've done an unwind on the genres previously). So the same the same book can appear two times by different genres. I don't know if that would change something, or if I should open a new threat.

Comment: Try to put `$setUnion` like this: `$setUnion: [ "$$value", [ "$$this" ] ]` and maybe it works.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot do that directly in the $group stage. Instead of that, you have to use an $addFields stage and use [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) and [$setUnion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/), to concat arrays without doubles.
Then you can just add a field with your new array size, and do the $sort.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$author",
      genres: {
        $push: "$genres"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      genres: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$genres",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            $setUnion: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      countGenres: {
        $size: "$genres"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[You can test here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ara0BB6x_hH)

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've just realized that I posted a wrong database example, in my database all there is only one genre per document  (I've done an unwind on the genres previously). So the same the same book can appear two times by different genres. I don't know if that would change something, or if I should open a new threat.

Comment: better to open a new one